# How can I combine rows from spark databricks

Tags: python, sql, apache-spark, databricks

I'm trying to combine rows in Spark.

The dataset has rows of Year, Zip code, HPI_with_2000_based, etc. I selected three zip codes and their information of HPI_with_2000_based. What I want to do is I want to combine these rows(three zip codes and their HPI_with_2000_based) and Year after 2000.

When I typed like this and it worked:

```
df6 = spark.sql("select ZipCode,Year, HPI_with_2000_base from df1 where ZipCode = 94122 or ZipCode = 10583 or ZipCode = 91411")
```

Resulting dataframe:

```
+-------+----+------------------+
|ZipCode|Year|HPI_with_2000_base|
+-------+----+------------------+
|  10583|1976|             16.66|
|  10583|1977|             16.81|
|  10583|1978|             18.37|
|  10583|1979|             23.06|
|  10583|1980|             24.37|
|  10583|1981|             30.82|
|  10583|1982|             32.46|
|  10583|1983|             35.25|
|  10583|1984|             42.15|
|  10583|1985|             48.94|
|  10583|1986|             57.22|
|  10583|1987|             66.24|
|  10583|1988|             76.98|
|  10583|1989|             77.28|
|  10583|1990|             74.44|
|  10583|1991|             69.85|
|  10583|1992|             70.86|
|  10583|1993|             70.98|
|  10583|1994|             71.39|
|  10583|1995|             71.27|
+-------+----+------------------+
only showing top 20 rows
```

However, when I typed like this, it failed:

```
df6 = spark.sql("select ZipCode,Year, HPI_with_2000_base from df1 where ZipCode = 94122 or ZipCode = 10583 or ZipCode = 91411" or Year >= '2000'").show()
```

Can you advise that what should I do to get a result?
Thank you.

Comment: Use `where ZIPCODE IN (94122, 10583, 91411)` in your query to make it more readable and easier to change.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question correctly, you want to add the condition `Year >= 2000` to the current SQL statement. Your `"` seems a bit misplaced and you need to surround the `ZipCode or ZipCode or ZipCode` part with parenthesis. A working statement can look like this:

```
val df6 = spark.sql("""select ZipCode, Year, HPI_with_2000_base from df1 
                         where ZipCode IN(94122, 10583, 91411) and Year >= 2000""")
```